# How can I upload a file, cross domain, via Ajax (File API) to a NodeJS (Express) server?

Tags: ajax, html, node.js, file-upload, cross-domain

I've been browsing the net and SO for the answer to this but I have come up short.

I have a NodeJS server (with express) on one domain that acts as a stateless API. It can receive a POST request that should handle a file upload.

Most of the examples I have found with NodeJS (express), and Ajax (mostly JQuery) file uploads have not supported cross domain uploads.

I have found [an article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) that talks about a method that supports cross domain file uploads but I have not found a way to handle that file upload within NodeJS.

I have tried using connect-form and formidable, but as far as I can see, it does not work cross domain. (res.files is always undefined)

Can anyone point me in the right direction, (I don't need fully working solutions, just which way to go since all of this tech is changing so rapidly.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS Web App File Upload Chops Off Beginning Of File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065042/nodejs-web-app-file-upload-chops-off-beginning-of-file)

Comment: This SO question answered my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065042/nodejs-web-app-file-upload-chops-off-beginning-of-file